# How to move bitshift to other side of equation

Tags: java, bit-shift

if I have this:

```
var5 = (this.unknownInt1900 >> 4) - 1;
```

and I know the value of `var5`

how do I solve for `unknownInt1900`?

E.g. `unknownInt1900 = var5 + 1` (and I don't know what do with the bitshift here)

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking, `x >> 4` **is** `x / 2**4` (or `x/16`).

Comment: How about `(var5+1) << 4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not reversible if you had data in the lower 4 bits. If you know that those bits are empty, just add and left shift:

```
unknownInt1900 = (var5 + 1) << 4;
```